# Updating data to associated model of another model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I created a bunch of codes that will update a field of associated model of another model.

I have 3 models:

```
1. Review
2. Application
3. Stat
```

**In my ReviewsController.php**

```
           foreach ($this->request->data['Review']['Mentee'] as $mentee) {

                $this->loadModel('Application');
                $this->Application->id = $mentee;
                pr($this->Application);
                $this->Application->Stat->saveField('second_video_observation_completed', $this->request->data['Review']['third_video_setting']);
            }
```

I'm trying to update `second_video_observation_completed` field in `Stat` Model

pr output for `$this->Application`

http://pastebin.com/jBYL8dzp

And pr output for `$this->Application->Stat`

http://pastebin.com/iFD0nyjU

I checked the sql logs via DebugKit, but it's inserting new record instead of updating the associated `Stat` of `Application w/ id 858` record.

```
INSERT INTO `ntc_development`.`stats` (`second_video_observation_completed`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('0', '2014-04-23 07:49:58', '2014-04-23 07:49:58')
```

Comment: Why are you using `foreach`? Cakephp saves all your associated data automatically....

Comment: I'm updating data per each `Application` . I edited the code above.

Comment: I think there is a easy way... Let me see your view file...

Comment: Here's my view file: http://pastebin.com/434akBC6 and my method in ReviewsController http://pastebin.com/xUCiSkS9

Comment: You view file is very long to look through.. I would like to see debug($this->request->data)...

Comment: And what is the relation between this three tables??

Answer (score 0):

To use `saveField` on `Stat` model You need to set `id` for `Stat` model not `Application` model.

```
$this->Application->Stat->id = 'YOUR_ID';
$this->Application->Stat->saveField('second_video_observation_completed', $this->request->data['Review']['third_video_setting']);
```

Comment: What if `Stat` is associated to the `Application`? But `Stat` doesn't have relationship w/ `Review` ? Is there any way to get that?

Comment: If you want to use `saveField` then no. That's they way that method works. You can for ex read proper `Application` with related `Stat` (using contain) and then use `saveField` on `Stat` model.